# Connection to SQL Server 2008: error 18452

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc

I have a problem with connection to SQL Server 2008.

My problem is all simple user can't connect to SQL Server 2008 but just the admin in subdomain only who can connected.

I test the connection with these steps:

1. control panel / set up odbc
2. system DNS / I choose SQL Server
3. click on the bottom Add
4. in the Name=test, and the server = I choose `SQLSERVER`

When I clicked Next bottom I have error 18452.

> Connection failed: SQLState: '28000'
>   SQL Server Error: 18452
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] connection failed.

Comment: Please post the **complete and exact** error message. Most likely, you just use a wrong server and instance name, or a wrong username&password

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is my complete and exact error message:Connection failed:
SQLState: '28000'
SQL Server Error:18452
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] connexion failed.
The connection comes from an area not Approved and can not be used with Windows authentication. Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Error: 18452

> Login failed for user ". The user is not associated with a trusted SQL
>   Server connection.

You should create new DSN with changed *Authentication Mode* from *Windows Authentication Mode* to *SQL Server Authentication*. Then specify login and pass for connection. This login should be added on SQL too.

Comment: the problem is like that: when i connect with sa in the client computer, i can connect!! but when i connect with a simple user who use Windows Authentification, connection is failed!! My goal is to connect the user using Windows Authentification only. and i don't know how can i resolve this problem!!

Comment: I think, you need to add user's Windows Account as login in SQL/Security/Logins. Or create on Windows one accounts group with collected user's  accounts and add this group as login in security section.

Comment: can you explain more or give me the step by step because i'm new in sql server 2008, please and thank you for your answer!!

Comment: @user If users work in domain: add each user to SQL logins e.g. by `CREATE LOGIN [DOMAINNAME\username] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]`. If you don't have domain (only Workgroup) you should create user on server with identical name and password, then add this local user with  `CREATE LOGIN [SERVER\username] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]`. I think, it's better to use _Sql Server Authentication_ in this situation.

Comment: ok, thank you very much!! i will try your solution and if you resolve my problem i will post here,if there is a problem i post the problem!! thank you!!

Comment: i have try your solution but my problem is not resolve!! there are a user who work in domain and a user who don't work in domain. for the user who work in domain, no problem!! but the problem is for the user out of domain!! please help me again!! your help save my life!

Comment: If your Sql server work in domain, you can't use _Windows Authentication_ for users out of domain.

Answer (score 0):

I were trying to do the same, saw a lot of videos trying to accomplish the add of the DSN but this was my solution.

I'm running Windows Server 2016:

I ran the ODBC 64bit -> System DSN tab -> Add button

Then I selected SQL Server, since i had SQL Server Management Studio 17.

I putted a Name and the fact that is really important: Write the SQL Server you know you have connection to on the Server field.

Be sure you had configured the Security on Server authentication for SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode and then write the user you know that have access to that Data Base.

Last step: you click next after putting the info of the user that have acces to the SQL Server and the connection will pass.

Hope this help someone.